# How does the scoring work in Black Ops?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops

When playing BO last night, my score on the screen was 450. When it showed the final team breakdown, I was on top with about 1600!

How is the scoring worked out? I see the scores for kills, assists, etc, but I can't figure out the final scoring system.

The scores I refer to are the ones you see as the game ends with the final kill cam (usually 600 for me), and the scores where you see the team breakdown after the kill cam has finished (1600 after my best game).

Comment: It would be useful to know where you are referring to when you say "my score on the screen was 450" - Which screen do you mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends strongly on what game type you play.  Games like team deathmatch that are based on a team getting a certain amount of kills award 100 points for a kill and a variation of 20-80 (based on how much damage you did to the opponent before he was killed for an assist).  There are a lot of different game types, if you list which one I will be happy to give you specifics.  Its important to note these are the 'standard' scoring systems.  If you play on a PC the game lobby can have its own rules/scoring.

Here is some information I found on different game type scoring (its not completely comprehensive but may help)

- Team Deathmatch is the standard 6 on 6 fight to the death, with a score limit of 7500 points, with each kill worth 100.
  Mercenary is Team Deathmath, only you can't bring in a party of players; fight against your friends.
- Free for All is the standard every-man-for-himself deathmatch mode we know and love.
- Domination is the 3-point objective mode; capture and hold points until your score is 200
- Ground War is either Team Deathmatch or Domination with larger parties; 9 vs 9.
  Demolition sets a team of defenders to stop a team of attackers from planting two bombs and detonating them in a time limit.
- Sabotage Each team has a bomb site to defend and there's only one bomb to fight over; get it and plant it to win!
- Headquarters spawns a location semi-randomly on the map, and it's your team's job to capture and hold it until 250 points!
- Capture the Flag is capture the flag. Self-explanitory. Score limit of 3 captures per round.
- Search & Destroy sets one team of defenders and one team of attackers with a single bomb and two bomb sites. The twist? No respawns!
- Team Tactical is Team Deathmath, Domination, Capture the Flag, Demolition, and Search & Destroy, but with 4 players per team instead of 6.

Answer (score 0):

The score after final killcam is the score for one round, while team breakdown shows the score for the whole match.

Answer (score -1):

Its possible the boost in points was due to completing the challenges and any contracts you may have taken out. Those point gains are not included in your in-game score at the time, but get added on at the end (in my experience anyway).

Comment: the points for challenges are not displayed on the score screen, they are displayed afterwards upon being returned to the lobby.